# Random draw without replacement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, random

I want to have a PHP code to draw some ids one by one without replacement randomly from a table in MySQL database.

Now I implement it like this:

There is a table called box

```
CREATE TABLE box
(
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Say it contains 15 records,

box

```
id:
=====
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
=====
```

The ids that have been drawn will be recorded and excluded in next draw.

For example,

at the start, the SQL for drawing will be

```
SELECT id FROM box RAND() LIMIT 1;`.
```

Say the result is 4.

Then I have drawn 4, the next SQL for drawing will be

```
SELECT id FROM box WHERE id != 4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Say the result is 6 this times.

That is, I have drawn 4 and 6, so the next SQL for drawing will be

```
SELECT id FROM box WHERE id != 4 AND id != 6 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"
```

The problem is that:

If the table 'box' contains 2000 records and I have drawn 1000+ ids, the next SQL for drawing will be very long. **I wonder would a longer SQL statment make the program or the process in MySQL run slower?** If yes, is there a **solution/design/algorithm** to solve this problem? **The records in the table may increase so I cannot make a random sequence on ids before the drawing.**

---

More about the problem:

the PHP code will be called by multiple users, so each user has some different ids that have been drawn by him/her.

Actually, in my current design, the ids that have been drawn by a user are stored in PHP session variable. When a user wants to draw, the ids stored in session variable will be accessed for the drawing SQL as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the queries written will take approximately the same time as your query.

By the way the conditions in your query are equivalent to a NOT IN and it may easier for you to apply a NOT IN

```
SELECT * FROM box WHERE id NOT IN (a[0],a[1]...)
```

Now as to whether the increased size of the query will slow down MySQL the answer is no, not really.

An article about why it won't slow it down is [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7565644027229) (remember your query is equivalent to a not in)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add another column to the table indicating whether or not that number has been drawn?

Then your query simply becomes:

`SELECT id FROM box WHERE drawn = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

And then, afterwards:

`UPDATE box SET drawn = 1 WHERE id = 43` or whatever ID you drew.

Comment: It is because multiple users will use the code to draw the id.
Actually, the ids that have been drawn is saved in session.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...why does it matter how many users are drawing the numbers? Are you saying each number can be drawn once for each user? In this case, create an additional table mapping users to numbers that have been drawn for that user

Answer (score 1):

If the box has a fixed number of records, then I would be inclined to take an approach the users more space but should run faster.  You approach requires a full table scan to retrieve the next value, because of the `order by rand()`.

Instead, create a separate "box" for each user and do the random ordering initially:

```
CREATE TABLE userbox (
    userboxid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    int boxid,
    userid int,
    PRIMARY KEY (userboxid),
    KEY (userid, userboxid)
);
```

Then, when a user starts, insert into that user's box:

```
insert into userbox
    select id, <userid>
    from box
    order by rand()
```

Subsequent retrievals would use a select statement such as:

```
select boxid
from userbox
where userboxid > <last user box id> and userid = <userid>
limit 1
```

The advantage of this approach is that after the overhead of populating the boxes, each retrieval of the next id should simply require looking at the next value in the index and fetching the box id from the data page.

Comment: Good design! but unfortunately the records in box will sometimes increase.

Comment: Do the changes in the box affect users who are currently accessing the box or only new users who are starting anew?

Answer (score 0):

You could have another table for the numbers drawn by each user

```
user_id     id
  1         129
  1         832
  2         23
 ...
```

then

```
SELECT id FROM box WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM user_drawn WHERE user_id=1) RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is another solution similar to my current. Instead of storing ids in session variable, your design stores ids in database. However, your design would make this table have numerous records.

I am looking forward to an elegant structure design to solve this problem!><

Comment: tables can have thousands of thousands of records. what are you working with a spectrum 48k?

Comment: I know the table can have thousands of thousands of records. But would too many records make the program run very slowly?